# VBA: select entire column in non-contiguous range

Tags: vba, range

I honestly tried googling but no luck.

I have a range, let's say

```
dim rng1 as range, rng2 as range, rng3 as range
set rng1 = "A1:F4"
set rng2 = "A6:F9"
set rng3 = union( rng1, rng2 )
```

Now I want to enter formula `=sum(1+1)` in all cells within that range, which are in column 3 of that range, so 
`C1:C4 = sum(1+1), C6:C9 = sum(1+1)`

When I do

```
rng1.columns(3).formula = "=sum(1+1)"
```

vba only inputs the formula in C1:C4. I suppose it happens because my range is non-contiguous. Is there a way to keep it one line and accomplish the task?

So far I manage via something like

```
dim i as integer
dim arr1(0 to 1) as range
arr1(0) = rng1
arr1(1) = rng2
for i = 0 to ubound(arr1)
    arr1(i).column(3).formula = "=sum(1+1)"
next i
```

I haven't tried a possible workaround via `Intersect`, something along the lines

```
rng4 = intersect( range("A1:F9"), rng3)
rng4.formula = "=sum(1+1)"
```

But I doubt it will work since rng will be yet another non-contiguous range.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that first line shouldn't be rng**3**.columns(3).formula = "=sum(1+1)", rather than rng1?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line:

```
Application.Intersect(rng3, rng3.Worksheet.Columns(3)).Formula = "=sum(1+1)"
```